# Does there exist $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n$, $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=c^{2n+1}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, pythagorean-triples, fermat-numbers

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$,  $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Is it possible that there are a,b,c that fulfill the following equation for every $(2n+1)$?

$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=c^{2n+1}$

$(i.e \quad a^3+b^3=c^3, a^5+b^5=c^5......)$

Comment: Yes, pick any $a$ and $b$ you like from $R$ and take $c = \left(a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}\right)^{1/(2n+1)}$

Comment: It seems like the OP is asking that $c$ satisfies that equation *for all* $n$ simultaneously

Comment: $a=0, b=c$ and $b=0, a=c$ and $c=0, a=-b$ both work with a special case $a=b=c=0$.  I doubt there are other solutions simultaneously for all $n$ when none are zero

Comment: The title deceived me!

Comment: @Araske Now it's more clear!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b,c$ satisfy the above equation for all $n$. We have $$ c =(a^{2n+1} + b^{2n+1})^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$$ If this holds for every $n$, it holds in limit, and so by a fact about $L^p$-norms $c = \sup \{a,b\}$. Then, say $c=a$ WLOG. Then, for the property to hold for $n=1$ we need $b = 0$.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about but my intuition tell me that this is a good answer! a=c and b=0 seems to be the only possible solution!